# Absolute import works with pytest but fails when running with python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I setup my project similar to other projects (like [Numpy](https://github.com/numpy/numpy) and [Pandas](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas), i.e. using the project name as a directory):

**Directory structure:**

```
/project_name
    project_name/
        utils/
            __init__.py
            utils.py
        tests/
            __init__.py
            test.py
        __init__.py
```

**Contents:**

```
# /project_name/project_name/__init__.py  (empty)

# /project_name/project_name/utils/__init__.py
from .utils import foo

# /project_name/project_name/utils/utils.py
def foo(x):
    return x

# /project_name/project_name/tests/test.py
from project_name.utils import foo

def test_foo():
    assert foo("1") == "1"
```

My working directory is `/project_name`, when I run `python project_name/tests/test.py` I get an ImportError, but interestingly when I use pytest the import works just fine:

```bash
$ cd /project_name

$ python project_name/tests/test.py
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project_name'

$ pytest
> =================== 1 passed in 1.76s ===================
```

I'm trying to follow the [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) standard of using absolute imports for scripts and I do not want to have to modify sys.path or PYTHONPATH. I'm a bit confused why running the script causes the import to fail while when using pytest, the import works just fine. My python version is 3.10, how can I structure the project such that the running `python project_name/tests/test.py` works as expected?

Additional follow up, is there a [PEP8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) practice for where to place scripts? I recall reading that scripts inside a package is an anti-practice, but couldn't find any reference to this. If there is a practice for this, how would the imports be written?

Comment: Add `__init__.py` under `/project_name/project_name`

Comment: Sorry edited the question, there was an __init__.py already present in /project_name/project_name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `python project_name/tests/test.py` runs the module with an incorrect `sys.path`.

[Use `-m` instead](https://docs.python.org/3.11/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) to run that file as the `__main__` module without touching `sys.path`:

```
python -m project_name.tests.test
```

Comment: Thanks! This seemed to work. Is there a practice for where to place Python scripts? I feel like using `python -m project_name.test.test` is a very hacky way if project_name/tests/test.py was a Python executable. It seems more natrual to run `python path/to/script.py`

Comment: It's not a hacky way at all, it's _the_ way to run a module from a package (aside from [console_scripts](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html), which are basically a wrapper for this). You could of course have a `run_tests.py` in your project root, which did `from project_name.test.test import main; main()` or similar and you'd then invoke `python run_tests.py`, but... no point in that since this is The Way.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Is there any way to make the python executable from the CLI? (i.e. is there a way to modify the shebang such that doing `./project_name/tests/test.py` would work?

Comment: For a properly distribution-packaged piece of software, `console_scripts`, as linked above. But really, I don't quite see why you'd need that since `python -m project_name.tests.test` works.